# How to show a world map from javascript on local file:// URL

Tags: javascript

I have an offline Javascript application plotting solar eclipse areas on a world map using orthographic projection in canvas.
It is a 2013 d3.v3.js using a world map stored in world-110m.json. It works fine when using in a web server (i.e. http://localaddress/....) but when using file:// (e.g. on a device not allowing web servers like iOS), it issues an error :

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///mylocalpath/world-110m.json. (Reason: CORS request not http)*

It used to be OK but in newer browsers this error occurs. Inspecting the code in d3.v3.js reveals very complex code for loading the world map.

I was trying to load this JSON locally by just copying the json to js and prepending 'var theworld=' to the json code and adding a line to the code:

```
<script src="world-110m.js"></script>
```

That loads without errors, but how can I load this json (which is just a Javascript) object without using XMLHttpRequest() or other complex code ?

Option two: I found much more recent versions op topojson but there were no working examples for loading just a simple world map of coastlines, showing content shapes.

Is there a simple way to plot a world map in a javascript canvas from a local file:// html file with including javascripts ?

Comment: Use a local server rather than running it from the file directly? `npx serve` is an easy way to do that

Comment: Spinning up a local webserver with NodeJS (`npm i serve; serve .`) or even PHP (`php -S localhost:9000`) is trivial and will solve your issue, but if you really insist on using a local file:/// address, use a `<input type="file">`, and manually load the json data `onchange` after each page reload.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the answer.

I load the world map json file as if it were a js file (it is actually an array) prepending it by assigning it to a variable: "var theworld = [the very long world map json]" (without quotes) and included it with the js extension in the html:

```
<script src="world-110m.js"></script>
```

The original code was:

```
d3.json("./world-110m.json", function(error, world) {
console.log(topojson.object(world, world.objects.land));
var land = topojson.object(world, world.objects.land),
  globe = {type: "Sphere"};
  context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

  context.strokeStyle = '#766951';

  context.fillStyle = '#88C0FF';
  context.beginPath(), path.context(context)(globe), context.fill(),       context.stroke();

  context.fillStyle = '#d7c7ad';
  context.beginPath(), path.context(context)(land), context.fill(), context.stroke();
```

});

This I replaced by eliminating the call to d3.json and the closing });, replaced the variable name 'world' by 'theworld' (the latter probably not necessary I could have use the variable name 'world' rather than 'theworld' in the modified world map js(on).).

```
console.log(topojson.object(theworld, theworld.objects.land));

var land = topojson.object(theworld, theworld.objects.land),
  globe = {type: "Sphere"};
  context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

  context.strokeStyle = '#766951';

  context.fillStyle = '#88C0FF';
  context.beginPath(), path.context(context)(globe), context.fill(), context.stroke();

  context.fillStyle = '#d7c7ad';
  context.beginPath(), path.context(context)(land), context.fill(), context.stroke();
```

Now it works flawlessly in both file:// and http(s):// .

That cross-origin request blocked is really weird for a local website. When it is pure locally, this should not be blocked.

Comment: "When it is pure locally, this should not be blocked." — Attacker sends you an HTML document as an email attachment. Harmless, right? Double it it, your email client saves it to a temporary file and opens it in a browser. Now its local. Now it can guess at whatever file names it likes on your hard disk (e.g. standard save locations for common accounting packages) and upload them to the attacker's server. *really not safe*.